# Distincting with Joint query

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.Projectnaam, P.ProjectStatus, P.ID, L.Stukey, L.ProjectKey
FROM Projecten P, Projectleden L
WHERE P.ProjectStatus = 'Open' || P.ProjectStatus = 'Dicht' && 
      L.Stukey = '400049093' &&
      P.ID = L.ProjectKey &&
      Projectnaam LIKE '%" . $in . "%'
```

There are 3 records with 'Open' in it, but it shows every possible combination in the output. How do I distinct in on 'Projectname'?

[The result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h54uQ.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You might want to use parantheses when dealing with `and` and `or` in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.Projectnaam, P.ProjectStatus, P.ID, L.Stukey, L.ProjectKey
FROM Projecten P inner join Projectleden L
on P.ID = L.ProjectKey 
WHERE 
  P.ProjectStatus in ('Open','Dicht') && 
  L.Stukey = '400049093' &&
  Projectnaam LIKE '%" . $in . "%'
```

also use joins while including more than one tables otherwise it takes the cartesian product ending up in showing all possible combinations.

Comment: I'd suggest p.projectstatus in ('Open', 'Dicht') - slightly easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to use paranthesis if there are "AND" and "OR" in where clause.
And also you didn't join those two tables it will give result based on cross join, So try to join those 2 tables based on relationship between them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.Projectnaam, P.ProjectStatus, P.ID, L.Stukey, L.ProjectKey
FROM Projecten P join Projectleden L on (your joining condition)
WHERE (P.ProjectStatus = 'Open' or P.ProjectStatus = 'Dicht') and
      L.Stukey = '400049093' and
      P.ID = L.ProjectKey and
      Projectnaam LIKE '%" . $in . "%'
```